# Unable to authenticate with mongodb

Tags: mongodb, authentication, authorization

Currently trying to setup authentication for the mongo version 4.2.15 server I use, but every time I try to login to the server, I end up getting authentication failed.

I setup an admin role, in the hopes of creating a user that could access all the databases and collections:

```
use admin
db.createUser({user: "test_admin",pwd: "admin", roles: ["dbAdminAnyDatabase"]})
```

After after setting authorization to enabled in the configuration:

```
security:
  authorization: "enabled"
```

and restarting the server, I found that the user refuses to authenticate:

```
> db.auth("test_admin", "admin")
Error: Authentication failed.
0
```

I also tried making a different user, with read write permissions to specific databases:

```
db.createUser({user: "test_admin2",pwd: "test", roles: [{ role: "readWrite", db: "birthday_parties" }
```

But that made no difference.

Comment: `use admin;` before?

Comment: Yes, to switch to the admin database.

Comment: You must also grant role `userAdminAnyDatabase`. Role `dbAdminAnyDatabase` grants only to read/write to any database but does not grant user administration

Comment: what I meant, are you sure that you call `db.auth("test_admin", "admin")` on admin db?

Comment: @dododo No, I thought this was for the whole mongo server.  I just ran "use admin", and then called db.auth, and now its working.

Is there anyway to apply this to all the dbs and collections on the server, instead of just one database?  Or do I need to apply it to each collection individually?